# How to get Followers count

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am add following Functionality to seller. How to get seller following count in that page

```
 <?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 
        $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'followup'))
        ->where('userdata.cus_mail=?', $email);
        $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
        if(!$alldata){?>

            <!-- Followers -->
    <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('followup/index/follow') ?>" method="post" id="follow-up">
        <?php $myStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ?>
        <?php if($myStatus): ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="sellerid" name="sellerid" value="<?php echo $partner->getMageuserid();?>" class="Follow-up-email-sellerid">
            <input type="submit" value="Follow Up" class="Follow-up-email">
            <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');?>" title="Customer Register">Follow Up</a></li>
        <?php endif ?>
    </form>
    <!-- Followers -->


            <?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
            $query = "insert into followup "
                                 . "(name,seller_id, cus_mail) values "
                                 . "(:name, :seller_id, :cus_mail)";

            $binds = array(
                              'name'    => $name,
                              'seller_id'   => $sellerid,
                              'cus_mail' => $email);
            $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
            //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Following');
         }
        else{?>

            <input type="submit" value="Following" class="Follow-up-email" readonly>
        <?php }?>
```

Also i want to restrict user follow same Seller More then one time

Comment: it email related to customer or seller id?

Comment: Count related to Seller ID

Comment: i mean which is related to customer i mean cannot add same email twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you check with

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'marketplace_userdata'))
->wher‌​e('userdata.email=?', $email); //change on ur requirement seller_id or eamil
$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
if(!$alldata){
    //insert new record
 }else {
   //you are already listed as follower
 }
```

for count

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'marketplace_userdata'))
    ->wher‌​e('userdata.seller_id=?', $seller_id); 
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
   echo count($alldata);
```

Comment: add that code too

Comment: Okay i will check it

Comment: Count i understand But 1st thing i can't understand can you please explain it

Comment: first thing is for `Also i want to restrict user follow same Seller More then one time` not add new record if it already there..

Comment: Thanks I Have one doubt After Follwing I wan to set Follow button as a readonly

Comment: first code will be use for that...

Comment: Ya it's working. I am not getting

Comment: in the place of add new add button for adding new and in else add disabled button simple

Comment: You mean add this code into phtml not a controller right

Comment: yes you can use it anywhere you want..

Comment: Okay i will check

Comment: If i add everything as a phtml how i submit form there is no method right

Comment: i already give you solution for form submit add you field put submit button and you will get values.

Comment: I have a problem on FOllowers can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107254/seller-following-not-working