# Seller Following Not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I Have Try to store followers on store Database. I have some Problem

```
 <?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'followup')) ->where('userdata.cus_mail=?', $email)->where('userdata.seller_id=?', $sellerid);
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
     if(!$alldata){?>
    <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('followup/index/follow') ?>" method="post" id="follow-up">
        <?php $myStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ?>
        <?php if($myStatus): ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="sellerid" name="sellerid" value="<?php echo $partner->getMageuserid();?>" class="Follow-up-email-sellerid">
            <input type="submit" value="Follow Up" class="Follow-up-email">
            <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');?>" title="Customer Register">Follow Up</a></li>
        <?php endif ?>
    </form>
    <?php }
    else{?>
        <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('followup/index/follow') ?>" method="post" id="follow-up">
        <?php $myStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ?>
        <?php if($myStatus): ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="sellerid" name="sellerid" value="<?php echo $partner->getMageuserid();?>" class="Follow-up-email-sellerid">
            <input type="submit" value="Following" class="Follow-up-email">
            <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');?>" title="Customer Register">Follow Up</a></li>
        <?php endif ?>
    </form>

   <?php  }?>
```

I can't able to find out the problem. What Mistake I done here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in controller otherwise on every refresh it will insert the data in amdin

```
 $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
            $query = "insert into followup "
                                 . "(name,seller_id, cus_mail) values "
                                 . "(:name, :seller_id, :cus_mail)";

            $binds = array(
                              'name'    => $name,
                              'seller_id'   => $sellerid,
                              'cus_mail' => $email);
            $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
            //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Following');
```

Comment: Then how i restrict that button if already follow it show Following else it show follow up

Comment: i told check it the same seller id or email in database.

Comment: Okay i will check

Comment: One customer can't able to follow more then one seller what is the problem

Comment: what is unique of customer?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake only i got it I made customer Mail as unique

Comment: If you don't mine please tell me how to check before insert table email & seller id available or not

Comment: you can add this query to check both `$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 
        $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'followup'))
        ->where('userdata.cus_mail=?', $email)->where('userdata.seller_id=?', $sellerid);`

Comment: Where i need to add before if condition

Comment: yes add it there...

Comment: Check my updated question what is the problem

Comment: where you adding this code?

Comment: Controller file..

Comment: Check now i update full method

Comment: it is inserting the data or not?

Comment: yes but same user multiple time also possible

Comment: your sellerid variable is not correct in condition change it there.

Comment: Thanks But how i disable button if already follow

Comment: bro same condition for disable put else condition and add disabled button there

Comment: In controller or phtml file

Comment: where you are displaying the button

Comment: frontend phtml file

Comment: so add the code there.........................

Comment: What is the problem in my phtml

Comment: where are the variable??

Comment: Ya got it thanks sorry little bit confusion